# Comment control from YAML in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to control a comment from my YAML header with a parameter, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is an example of my code.

```
---
title:  My report
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default  
params:
  optional_text: "TRUE"
---

`r if(optional_text){"My text"}`
```

I have tried a few things (with/without quotation marks, etc.), but I always end up with the same error

*Error in eval(parse_only(code[i]), envir = envir) : 
  object 'optional_text' not found*

I have figured out a walkaround in the meanwhile, but it just doesn't seem efficient.

````
```{r label, include=FALSE}
optional_text<-TRUE
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change one little thing:

```
`r if(params$optional_text){"My text"}`
```

In RMD the parameters are called with `params$NAME_OF_PARAMETER`, see here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html